# Detect root_path (--root) in setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Is there any way in `setup.py` to know the `root_path` variable.

With `root_path` variable I'm refering to the directory specified as `--root`.

For example in this case:

```
python2 setup.py install --root=/home/drizzt/test --optimize=1
```

I need to find a way to have `/home/drizzt/test`

Answer (score 0):

The `setup` function returns a `setuptools.dist.Distribution` object which can be used to recover that info. First, it keeps a dictionary of command line arguments provided to sub-commands; that is accessible through the `get_cmdline_options` method. Second, you can ask it to return you the command object (in this case 'install' which is actually an instance of `setuptools.command.install.install`), which has a property called `root` that will contain the root directory provided on the command line.

```
dist = setup(< all your setup arguments >)
print(dist.get_cmdline_options())
icmd = dist.get_command_obj('install')
print(icmd.root)
```

Should produce something like...

```
< All your normal setup output >
...
{'install': {'root': '/home/drizzt/test', 'optimize': '1'}}
/home/drizzt/test
```